# How to create a dependency between a task and an extension?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have an Android gradle script as follows:

```
preBuild.dependsOn "editManfest"

task editManfest(type: Copy) {
   // copies and edits the AndroidManifest.xml
}

import com.android.builder.core.DefaultManifestParser
def extension = android {
    def manifestParser  = new DefaultManifestParser()
    def manifestVersion =   manifestParser.getVersionName(android.sourceSets.main.manifest.srcFile)
   ...
```

However the code in the extension is attempting to access the manifest file before the editManifest task has completed.

What can I do to ensure the task is completed before the extension's code attempts to access the manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your running into execution vs configuration time issue. The editManfest task will always execute after configuration configuring the android extension .

Can you add a

```
doLast {
  def manifestParser  = new DefaultManifestParser()
  def manifestVersion = manifestParser.getVersionName(android.sourceSets.main.manifest.srcFile)
}
```

to your editManfest task?